# How to access data properties in Vue 2 in script tag

Tags: vue.js, vue-data

I have defined a variable isShowDrop2

```
var app = new Vue({
      el: '#vueapp',
      data: {
        isShowDrop1: false,
        isShowDrop2: false,
      },
        methods: {
            drop_hide() {
               if (isShowDrop2 == false) {
                   // Do nothing
               } else {
                   isShowDrop1 = false
               }
            }
        }
});
```

Running `drop_hide()` throws a console error that says `isShowDrop2 is not defined`.

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/ayLw083b/

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference all the properties in `data` as properties of `this`.

```js
drop_hide() {
  if (this.isShowDrop2 == false) {
      // Do nothing
  } else {
      this.isShowDrop1 = false
  }
}
```